# Multiple domain in angular same application

Tags: angular

angular create middleware or allow  multihost:
How would work at an Angular so that the same application responds to two different domains to specify them will be the information shown, in django I have worked it for example with middleware but with angular I don't know how it would be.

www.domail1.com

www.domain2.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your deployment enviroment to **redirect** any upcoming traffic from any domain to your angular app. For example, AWS uses Route53 to add domain names and you can configure redirection to some url which host the production ready angular app.